# Periodicity of Wavefunction and Eigenvalues of Angular Momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, wavefunction, eigenvalue

I am currently looking through the following [paper on circuit quantum electrodynamics](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.3902) in order to explore connections between a Cooper pair Hamiltonian and the quantum rotor model. Here is an excerpt from page 7 that has caught my attention:

> The Cooper Pair Box (CPB) Hamiltonian is given by
> $H = 4E_c [\hat{n} − \hat{n}_g]^2 − E_J \cos(\hat{\phi}) $
> where $\hat{n}$ is the integer-valued Cooper pair number operator and $n_g$ is a continuous
> valued offset charge (or ‘gate charge’) representing dc bias intentionally applied to the
> qubit, low frequency stray electric fields in the system (‘charge noise’) as well as high
> frequency electric fields from photons in the cavity in which the qubit is placed. 4Ec
> is the charging energy for a Cooper pair and EJ is the Josephson tunneling energy. In
> the phase representation ... the wave function obeys $Ψ(ϕ + 2π) = Ψ(ϕ)$.
> As illustrated in figure 2, this corresponds to the Hamiltonian of a quantum rotor
> with moment of inertia controlled by the charging energy and gravitational potential
> controlled by the Josephson energy. $\hat{n}$ plays the role of the integer valued angular
> momentum of the rotor and the torque associated with the cosine potential changes the
> angular momentum up and down by one unit.

I see why $\hat{n}$ has integer-valued eigenvalues. However, the above text appears to suggest that if the wavefunction of quantum rotor is $2\pi$ periodic then the eigenvalues of the angular momentum must have integer eigenvalues. **Why is this true? How does one prove/show this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single-particle quantum system defined on a circle, the angular momentum operator is given by
$$
\hat{L} = -i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}
$$
An eigenstate of $\hat{L}$ must satisfy $\hat{L} \psi_m(\phi) = \hbar m \psi_m(\phi)$. By inspection, the eigenstates of $\hat{L}$ are
$$
\psi_m(\phi) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{i m \phi}
$$
By demanding $\psi_m(\phi + 2\pi) = \psi_m(\phi)$, it is immediately seen that $m$ must be an integer.

Another related comment: given an arbitrary wavefunction $\psi(\phi)$ satisfying the appropriate periodic boundary conditions, we can expand $\psi$ in Fourier series as follows:
$$
\psi(\phi) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} c_m e^{i m \phi}
$$
where $c_m$ are the Fourier coefficients for $\psi$. Immediately, you can see that this Fourier series is nothing more than an eigenmode decomposition in terms of the $\hat{L}$ eigenstates.

Comment: Thank you very much